# How to make text in math mode which would cause an `overfull \hbox` automatically start on the next line?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I have text within `$`s following normal text, which runs off the end of the line and creates an `overfull \hbox` warning.

By default, LaTeX doesn't let the stuff in math mode run off the end of the line, but it creates a line break at a certain place in the code.  How do I tell it to instead, by default, put a line break before the text in the `$`s starts?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Here is text which starts off the line.
We can write $A^n$ as $\bigcup_{a^{n-1} \in A^{n-1}} \{(a^{n-1}, a) \,:\, a \in A \}$.

More text, then I have something like the following
$(-3, 3)^{C} \textrm{ in } A = (-\infty, -3] \cup [3, \infty)$.

\end{document}
```

I'm getting line breaks after the `:` in the first sentence, and after the `\cup` in the second sentence.

P.S. Also, might there be a better way of creating a "such that" sign within a set written in math mode, instead of `\,:\,`?  Ideally, a `|` would be nice, preceded by and following spaces...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

Here is text which starts off the line.
We can write $A^n$ as 
\[
\bigcup_{a^{n-1} \in A^{n-1}} \{(a^{n-1}, a) : a \in A \}.
\]

More text, then I have something like the following
$(-3, 3)^{C}$ in $A = (-\infty, -3] \cup [3, \infty)$.

\end{document}
```

The complicated formula is best set in display mode; no added spaces around the colon, possibly instead after `\{` and before `\}`.

The second case has a big flaw: the word "in" must go outside math mode because it's text. If you want to avoid a break at `\cup`, write

```
\cup\nobreak
```

but leave these decisions for when the document is complete.

Answer (score 6):

My answer to this is not to write math like that; whenever I have an "overfull hbox" because of inline math, I realize that said math is way too complicated to be inline and switch it to a display.  Basically any math other than single symbols or, I suppose, very simple statements like `$x \in Y$`, should be displayed simply for reasons of good style.

To nitpick your code itself: if you are writing any kind of serious math you will probably want to use the `amsmath` package, which provides many helpful features and some improvements to the default ones.  In this case, it provides `\colon`, which is modified to have nice spacing of the sort you have given, and `\text`, which is a superior alternative to `\textrm` in math mode.

Comment: When you say "display," do you mean put inside `\[...\]` so that the math text is on its own line?  I may want to write something as simple as `$A = B \cup C$` within a paragraph, and if that happened to be towards the end of the line, LaTeX would automatically insert a line break after the `\cup`...

Comment: @jamaicanworm: Yes, I mean that.  If you want to discourage a particular break you *may* put braces around that part: `$A = {B \cup C}$`, which in math mode has the effect of creating an unbreakable `\hbox`, but beware that this increases the likelihood of the expression becoming too long and making an overfull `\hbox`.  Don't expect anything you put in the text to have total visual integrity; that is exactly what a display is for.

Comment: Actually, `\colon` is meant for expressions like `$f\colon A\to B$`.  I see nothing wrong with `$\{x:x>0\}$`, but you can always say `\newcommand{\setselector}[2]{\{#1\,:\,#2\}}` (or put `|` in place of `:`).

Comment: @mbork: I actually prefer to use `\mid` for set-building notation, but @jamaicanworm put some effort into making the colon look good so I figured he'd want the version that does it automatically.  In this case, what's good for the goose is good for the gander.

Comment: @Ryan: Using `\nobreak` (as egreg suggests) is superior to `{...}` since the former doesn't effect the spacing of the formula. The latter causes the spaces to be set to their natural width.