# How to tackle overfull using usepackage

Tags: overfull

I have many math expressions in my text. There are some overfull. If I try to fix one, a new overflow is generated. Is there any easy way, like some userpackage, to tackle this problem?

Comment: the problem is that your text is wider than your page, so you do not need a package, you need to adjust your text to make it fit.

Comment: if your math is inline and it is linebreaking causing overfull try `\sloppy` at the start of the document. If it is display math you need to adjust each display individually. As you have given no clues about your input, hard to guess.

Comment: Problem is if I try to adjust, since many math expressions are there, I get new overfull.

Comment: Without a MWE there's no *specific* advice we can give. *General* advices can be found in other questions e.g. [How to fix overfull in inline math? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/615975/how-to-fix-overfull-in-inline-math), [How to make text in math mode which would cause an `overfull \hbox` automatically start on the next line? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38209/how-to-make-text-in-math-mode-which-would-cause-an-overfull-hbox-automaticall) -- and yes, that's all there is.

Comment: Someone made this too. [macros - How to automatically detect overfull \hboxes for inline maths mode - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124207/how-to-automatically-detect-overfull-hboxes-for-inline-maths-mode)

Comment: Thanks a lot. \sloppy works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your math is inline and it is linebreaking causing overfull try `\sloppy` at the start of the document. If it is display math you need to adjust each display individually. As you have given no clues about your input, hard to guess. –